# Android String.xml (item/description)

Tags: java, android, xml, string

In android i want to make list view with names of people and when i click on each one i want to open another activity that shows clicked person and their description. I figured out how to make list of people and extract their names in java code but i can't figure out where should i write descriptions and how to extract them in java?

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">PumpingIron</string>
<string-array name="listItems">
    <item>Arnold Schwarzenegger</item>
    <item>Ronnie Coleman</item>
    <item>Kai Greene</item>
    <item>Phillip Heath</item>
    <item>Flex Wheeler</item>
</string-array>
```

For each of these i need to have description and be able to get that description when item is open in another activity.

Comment: It would make more sense if you stored those into SQLite

Comment: yes i know but we should do it with string resources since we did't learn database yet on android classes

Comment: The just store another `string-array` with the name `descriptions`, and know that the indices need to match for both arrays.

Comment: i think i will go with that solution for now

Answer (score 0):

This is more complex than a single string array. If you think about it a bit, in reality you have a String object, say, "Dave". "Dave" has multiple sub-properties in your project - for example, "Description", "Phone Number", "Facebook Address", etc.

Perhaps you could use a SQLLite model, or JSON Objects that you store somewhere.